# Issue while trying to load SOLR 4.0 admin UI

Tags: solr4

I have installed SOLR 4.0 in a linux server under /tmp directory. The SOLR server is started from /example directory using java -jar start.jar . The server has started and listening at port 8983.

**Issue:**
When I try to load admin UI via URL "//hostname:8983/SOLR" , the static part of page with menu items (dashboard,coreadmin etc.) is loaded but the actual configurations like free memory, used memory etc. are not getting loaded. I just the message "Loading" .

Below are some of the observations and last few entries from the log file. Can anyone advise, what might be wrong?

Regards

**Observations:**
1. Installed the same SOLR instance on my windows 7 PC and I can access the admin UI without any issues.
2. I do not see any errors in logs when SOLR is started thru java -jar start.jar . 
3. When the URL "hostname:8983/SOLR" I can see a log entry for the query but nothing after that
4. When I try "hostname:8983/solr/admin/system?wt=xml" I can see the configuration XML getting loaded with all the values including hostname being populated.

**Last few entries in the log**

2972 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  â user.dir=/tmp/solr-4.4.0/example
2973 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  â SolrDispatchFilter.init() done
3008 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector  â Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8983
3066 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  â [collection1] webapp=null path=null params={event=firstSearcher&q=static+firstSearcher+warming+in+solrconfig.xml&distrib=false} hits=0 status=0 QTime=92
3067 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  â QuerySenderListener done.
3067 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent  â Loading spell index for spellchecker: default
3068 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent  â Loading spell index for spellchecker: wordbreak
3068 [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  â [collection1] Registered new searcher Searcher@31be0369 main{StandardDirectoryReader(segments_1:1)}
51926 [qtp1798675483-18] INFO  org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter  â [admin] webapp=null path=/admin/cores params={indexInfo=false&*=1377543032093&wt=json} status=0 QTime=3
52158 [qtp1798675483-13] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  â [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/admin/system params={*=1377543032245&wt=json} status=0 QTime=82
598493 [qtp1798675483-15] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore  â [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/admin/system params={wt=xml} status=0 QTime=75

Answer (score 0):

admin pages are change u have use that

127.0.0.1:8983/solr/collection1/browse?q=

admin to changed collection1 so u just use that